# how to animate a gradient moving over an object

Tags: animation

Improving on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATYF1lPyMD0) tutorial, is there a way to animate the gradient so the colours move across the object?﻿

Comment: if I have configured the material of the cube as described above, how do I execute the animation?
Unfortunately I can't get the colors to move. Many thanks for the help !

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by animating the *Location* in the *Mapping* node, and adding a few math nodes between the *Separate XYZ* node and the *ColorRamp* node, like this:

[image]

The ColorRamp uses values between 0 and 1, and if you input anything outside this range, it gets clamped (i.e. anything greater than 1 becomes 1, and anything less than 0 becomes 0). These math nodes make sure you get a value in the expected range.

The *Modulo* node with the lower value set to 1, basically preserves only what comes after the decimal point, i.e. 1.5, 2.5, 3.5 and so on all become 0.5, and -1.5, -2.5, -3.5 and so on all become -0.5. So this gives us a value in the range -1 to 1.

The *Less Than* node with the lower value set to 0 outputs 1 if the upper input is below 0 and 0 if it's equal to or greater than 0.

The *Add* node simply adds the output from the Modulo and the Less Than nodes, thus fixing negative values. So now we have a value in the expected range.

[image]

To animate, hold the mouse pointer over the Location properties in the mapping node, and either press <kbd>I</kbd> or right click and select *Insert Keyframes* or *Insert Single Keyframe*. The former adds keyframes to all three location properties and the latter adds a keyframe to the one the mouse pointer is on. Move the timeline a number of frames, change the appropriate location value(s) and add keyframes again. Repeat as many times as needed.
N.B. The nodes above only affect the Z location. It can easily be changed to either the X or Y location, by using the corresponding output from the Separate XYZ.