# Stagger emission material animation

Tags: animation

So. I'm teaching myself Blender so i can create interesting videos for my music.
I have been doing well so for but I hit a snag.

Using the array modifier it has been quite easy to do interesting stuff especially with and empty in object offset.

But now I want to add a strobing light effect to my array.
for now I added a new emission material and animated the strength with a sine function "built in".
[image]

this is all fine and dandy but I was wondering how to stagger this animation on the array so the strobe travels along the objects.
would I need to offset the emission strength with some math and an empty?
I'm not sure where to go from here and have not yet found a solution.

I have tried the solution in this post.
[possible answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129918/how-to-animate-a-gradient-moving-over-an-object)
But while the solution does resemble what i'm trying to do it has the problem of showing the gradient on each cube / light source.
[image]
I'm trying to make each light source solid in color.

A solution i can do for now is add 5 or 10 separate lights and animate them individually, then group them and use an array mod on the group. if possible.

But the scene i'm trying to build is huge. so doing this over and over will take up a lot of time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to animate a gradient moving over an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129918/how-to-animate-a-gradient-moving-over-an-object)

Comment: Useful https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79851/make-an-objects-visibility-controlled-by-another-object-or-an-empty/

Comment: set the Color Ramp to Constant to avoid gradients

Comment: setting the Color Ramp to constant still creates a separation line in the emission material. I'm trying to create a softly blinking light and then stagger it on the next objects.

using the object coordinates may be the right direction though. I'm experimenting with it right now to see if i can use it to offset the Emission strength based on the object location. So far no luck though.